# Solving a linear equation with a double dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following linear matrix equation in two variables, $\mathbf{X}$ and $y$:
$$z = \mathbf{A}\colon\mathbf{X} + by$$
$$z = \sum_i^3\sum_j^3\mathbf{A}_{ij} \mathbf{X}_{ij} + by$$ where $z$, $b$ and $y$ are scalar, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are 3x3 matrices. With a series of $z$$(\mathbf{X},y)$, is there any way to calculate $\mathbf{A}$ and $b$?

I can calculate $z$ using the method which this equation is supposed to approximate, but which and how many $z(\mathbf{X},y)$ would be needed to figure out the linear approximation?

Context: this is for calculating the coupling between an imposed, far-field stress $\sigma^0_{ij} = \mathbf{X}_{ij}$ and a local shear stress $\sigma^1_{12} = z$, with a parameter related to geometry, $y$.

Attempts: Owing to the symmetry of $\sigma^0_{ij}$, I am able to represent the 3x3 matrices, $\mathbf{X}$, as 1x6 vectors, $\mathbf{x}$. I can solve the case where $b = 0$ by choosing 6 $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{M} = [\mathbf{x_1~x_2~\dots~x_6}] = c\mathbf{I}$. Where $c$ is a scalar. Then: $$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{M}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
           z(\mathbf{x}_1) \\
           z(\mathbf{x}_2) \\
           \vdots \\
           z(\mathbf{x}_6)
         \end{bmatrix}$$
However $b$ should not be 0 so this solution isn't quite what I need.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hi! I typed latex directly in the question input box and it seems to render fine on my PC am I missing something?

Comment: It looks strange here, but I saw what you wrote it it looks fine. Perhaps that there's some problem with MathJax. Sorry for the wrong alert.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't think of $\mathbf{X}$ as a $1\times 9$ vector rather than a $3\times 3$ matrix? Then your indexing just becomes $\sum_{k=1}^9\mathbf{A}_k\mathbf{X}_k+by$, i.e., $\vec{\mathbf{a}}\cdot\vec{\mathbf{x}}+by$, where $\vec{\mathbf{a}}$ and $\vec{\mathbf{x}}$ are $9$-component vectors.

Comment: Hi Steven. Yes that was my first instinct. You can represent X as a 1x6 vector which leads me to the solution I put at the end. Perhaps my issue is not with the double dot product but with the simultaneous solution for both A and b